# concatenate long strings of text for uploading on website

Tags: excel, concatenation

We have used the concatenate function on excel to add a string of text on excel. We are trying combine around 10 fields with a total of 300 characters. The concatenate function works on excel and once we paste the values to remove the formula, the correct text strings are created. However, the problem arise when we try to use this information as a CSV, tab delimited file to import into our webstore, the concatenate text is not recognised. When we inspect the format of the cell, the characters are displayed as a bunch of ############, rather than the text and I believe this is the reason why it is not allowing us to import the file. Small text strings work, however long strings do not work. We have to use open calc spreadsheet to concatenate, however this has the same problem. We have saved the file at UT8.

Comment: Is the value in the CSV ###### or is when you import the CSV that the text it translated into ######?

Comment: the field is display as the correct concatenate text string, if you right mouse click on the cell and bring up the format, under the number tab, the sample text is display as a bunch of ###### characters. I believe it is this text which is being translated.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have a cell to inspect if you are saving as a csv. You should have a text file to examine. You also don't need to paste the formulas as values, as none of the formulas will remain after you save as a text file.

After you get the Excel file ready with the concatenate formulas, save the sheet as either a tab-delimited .txt or comma-delimited .csv.

Open it up in notepad to verify that the values are still what you expect them to be rather than the ##### characters.

At that point, your import should work.

Comment: Prano, did you get this to work? You know you should accept answers if they do in fact answer your question. You'll get a few points for doing so, and it's the way the site works. If this isn't the answer, you can answer it yourself if you've solved the issue some other way.